# Can one make window server VM's use system RAM for file caching?

Tags: filesystems, nas, windows-server, windows-storage-server

When using Windows Server 2019 as a virtual machine for serving files, is it possible to convince it to use system RAM for caching to improve performance? We're running several file servers on a box, each with their own virtual disks. I'm trying to gain more speed here, and since the box has a bunch of RAM sitting unused, how can one make Windows cache the files in RAM for better performance?

TrueNAS, when installed on metal, uses ALL the system RAM. I think even Windows Server, when installed on the metal and using storage spaces, does the same thing. How can I make it do that when it's used as a VM?

Comment: VM Apps work by assigning memory in the VM settings (not the system memory). Have you tried this?

Comment: You need to allow the VM more RAM - caching is automatic and doesn't require convincing.

Comment: each VM has 32gb or RAM, and is using about 3 GB. i don't think it's being used

Comment: Have you over-assigned memory?  Total memory assigned for VMs should not more than 1/2 all host memory.  If you have assigned more, this may be what you are seeing

Comment: no, about half the host memory is used